# Finding the indexes of multiple/overlapping matching substrings

Tags: r, regex

I have a string, `s="CCCGTGCC"` and a subtstring `ss="CC"`. I want to get all the indexes in `s` that start the string `ss`. In my example I would want to get back the array `c(1,2,6)`.

Is there any string function that achieves this? Notice that my string is in the form `"CCCGTGCC"`, and not `c("C","C","C","G","T","G","C","C")`.

`grep` only returns whether there is a match anywhere in the string, and not the indexes of the matches within the string, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Did you mean array [1, 2, 7] (actually a vector in R)?

Comment: `gregexpr` is the function you are looking for, but the reg exp engine "swallows" tokens up, so "CCC" is counted as one "CC" and one "C", though some clever use of regexps may counter this.

Comment: notice about your notice, code : substring("abcde",1:5,1:5) breaks string "abcde" into vector of characters and paste((substring("abcde",1:5,1:5) ),collapse="") do the oposite

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try `gregexpr` with `perl=TRUE` and use perl regular expressions with look-ahead assertions (see `?regex`):

```
gregexpr("(?=CC)","CCCGTGCC",perl=TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 7
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 0 0 0
```

Comment: Meh, I was stuck, but didn't think of "looking ahead". I wonder why pattern = "CC" doesn't work...

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: see James' comment to the OP.  If a match is found, it is removed from the remainder of the string being searched.  Notice that the `"match.length"` is zero (it would be 2 if `pattern="CC"`).

Comment: +1 for the clarifying comment about the `"match.length"` of look-ahead assertions.  I'd never considered using that in this way.