# Regular expressions in R: finding multiple occurrences of patterns in character vectors

Tags: regex, r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding the indexes of multiple/overlapping matching substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878992/finding-the-indexes-of-multiple-overlapping-matching-substrings)

I have a character vector that looks like this

```
s <- c("aab", "aabaa", "aabaaa")
```

I want to search for all the occurrences of "aa" including overlapping occurrences, such that s[2] would have two occurrences (starting at position 1 and 4) and s[3] would have 3 occurrences (starting at positions 1, 4, and 5). That would look something like:

```
functionImLookingFor("aa", s)
> [[1]] 
> [1] 1
>
> [[2]]
> [1] 1
> [2] 4
> 
> [[3]]
> [1] 1
> [2] 4
> [3] 5
```

I'm new to using regular expressions, but none of the functions that I've found seem to be able to handle overlapping occurrences of patterns. What am I missing?

Comment: I've answered this before... let me search my answers.  [Found it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878992/finding-the-indexes-of-the-matching-substrings/7879329#7879329).