# Overlapping matches in R

Tags: regex, r, string, dna-sequence, stringi

I have searched and was able to find this [forum discussion](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-December/182576.html) for achieving the effect of overlapping matches.

I also found the following [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878992/finding-the-indexes-of-multiple-overlapping-matching-substrings) question speaking of finding indexes to perform this task, but was not able to find anything concise about grabbing overlapping matches in the R language.

I can perform this task in most any language that supports ([PCRE](http://pcre.org/)) by using a Positive Lookahead assertion while implementing a capturing group inside of the lookahead to capture the overlapped matches.

But, while actually performing this the same way I would in other languages, using `perl=T` in R, no results yield.

```
> x <- 'ACCACCACCAC'
> regmatches(x, gregexpr('(?=([AC]C))', x, perl=T))[[1]]
[1] "" "" "" "" "" "" ""
```

The same goes for using both the `stringi` and `stringr` package.

```
> library(stringi)
> library(stringr)
> stri_extract_all_regex(x, '(?=([AC]C))')[[1]]
[1] "" "" "" "" "" "" ""
> str_extract_all(x, perl('(?=([AC]C))'))[[1]]
[1] "" "" "" "" "" "" ""
```

The correct results that should be returned when executing this are:

```
[1] "AC" "CC" "AC" "CC" "AC" "CC" "AC"
```

### Edit

1. I am well aware that `regmatches` does not work well with captured matches, but what **exactly** causes this behavior in regmatches and why are no results returned? **I am scavenging for a somewhat detailed answer**.
2. Is the `stringi` and `stringr` package not capable of performing this over `regmatches`?
3. Please feel free to add to my answer or come up with a different workaround than I have found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard `regmatches` does not work well with captured matches (specifically multiple captured matches in the same string). And in this case, since you're "matching" a look ahead (ignoring the capture), the match itself is zero-length. There is also a `regmatches()<-` function that may illustrate this. Obseerve

```
x <- 'ACCACCACCAC'
m <- gregexpr('(?=([AC]C))', x, perl=T)
regmatches(x, m) <- "~"
x
# [1] "~A~CC~A~CC~A~CC~AC"
```

Notice how all the letters are preserved, we've just replaced the locations of the zero-length matches with something we can observe.

I've created a [regcapturedmatches()](http://gist.github.com/MrFlick/10413321) function that I often use for such tasks. For example

```
x <- 'ACCACCACCAC'
regcapturedmatches(x, gregexpr('(?=([AC]C))', x, perl=T))[[1]]

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
# [1,] "AC" "CC" "AC" "CC" "AC" "CC" "AC"
```

The `gregexpr` is grabbing all the data just fine so you can extract it from that object anyway you life if you prefer not to use this helper function.

Comment: +1 Interesting function you've created. I am well aware of zero-width matches, so basically regmatches and the other packages such as stringi, r are not meant to handle this?

Comment: I can't speak to `stringr` as I've never used that myself, but `regmatches` really focuses on the match rather than the capture (which are highly related by slightly different). I've added an additional sample to try to make it clear what the `regmatches()` is capturing compared to my function.`

Comment: Yea I've used `regmatches()<-` like that before hand to observe the effect of the zero-width matches.

Answer (score 7):

As far as a workaround, this is what I have come up with to extract the overlapping matches.

```
> x <- 'ACCACCACCAC'
> m <- gregexpr('(?=([AC]C))', x, perl=T)
> mapply(function(X) substr(x, X, X+1), m[[1]])
[1] "AC" "CC" "AC" "CC" "AC" "CC" "AC"
```

Please feel free to add or comment on a better way to perform this task.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it only works when the captured region is always 2 characters long.  A more general solution is this:

Comment: Oops.  I forgot I can't put code blocks in comments.  Will make this a separate answer.

Answer (score 5):

A `stringi` solution using a capture group in the look-ahead part:

```
> stri_match_all_regex('ACCACCACCAC', '(?=([AC]C))')[[1]][,2]
## [1] "AC" "CC" "AC" "CC" "AC" "CC" "AC"
```

Comment: Weird, how come it failed to work with `stri_extract_all_regex`

Comment: @hwnd: it's a 0-length match; `(?=...)` [does not](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp) advance the input position.

Comment: Yes I know it's a zero-width match =) I guess there is a difference between `extract_all_regex` and `match_all_regex`

Comment: No, the 1st column of the resulting matrix (the whole match) consists only of empty strings :)

Comment: Ok now I see and understand what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

Another roundabout way of extracting the same information that I've done in the past is to replace the `"match.length"` with the `"capture.length"`:

```
x <- c("ACCACCACCAC","ACCACCACCAC")
m <- gregexpr('(?=([AC]C))', x, perl=TRUE)
m <- lapply(m, function(i) {
       attr(i,"match.length") <- attr(i,"capture.length")
       i
     })
regmatches(x,m)

#[[1]]
#[1] "AC" "CC" "AC" "CC" "AC" "CC" "AC"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "AC" "CC" "AC" "CC" "AC" "CC" "AC"
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the additional solution. I've done similar using `capture.start` and `capture.length`.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a regex solution, and doesn't really answer any of your more important questions, but you could also get your desired result by using the substrings of two characters at a time and then removing the unwanted `CA` elements.

```
x <- 'ACCACCACCAC'
y <- substring(x, 1:(nchar(x)-1), 2:nchar(x))
y[y != "CA"]
# [1] "AC" "CC" "AC" "CC" "AC" "CC" "AC"
```

Answer (score 1):

An additional answer, based on @hwnd's own answer (the original didn't allow variable-length captured regions), using just built-in R functions:

```
> x <- 'ACCACCACCAC'
> m <- gregexpr('(?=([AC]C))', x, perl=T)[[1]]
> start <- attr(m,"capture.start")
> end <- attr(m,"capture.start") + attr(m,"capture.length") - 1
> sapply(seq_along(m), function(i) substr(x, start[i], end[i]))
[1] "AC" "CC" "AC" "CC" "AC" "CC" "AC"
```

Pretty ugly, which is why the `stringr` etc. packages exist.