# Positive look ahead in R - passing variables

Tags: regex, r, variables

I got stuck in a regular expression.
I usually use this line of code to find overlapping repetitions in strings:

```
gregexpr("(?=ATGGGCT)",text,perl=TRUE)
[[1]]
[1]  16  45  52  75 203 210 266 273 327 364 436 443 480 506 534 570 649
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

Now I want to give to `gregexpr` a pattern contained in a variable:

```
x="GGC"
```

and of course if I pass the variable `x`, `gregexpr` is going to search `"x"` and not what the variable contains

```
gregexpr("(?=x)",text,perl=TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] -1
attr(,"match.length")
[1] -1
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

How can I pass my variable to `gregexpr` in this case of positive look ahead?

Comment: ok I just solved it and the solution was quite easy:

    c=paste("(?=",x,")",sep="")
    r=gregexpr(c,text,perl=TRUE)

Comment: Put this as an answer to your question.  That's encouraged at SO.

Answer (score 5):

I'd play with the [`sprintf`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sprintf.html) function:

```
x <- "AGA"
text <- "ACAGAGACTTTAGATAGAGAAGA"
gregexpr(sprintf("(?=%s)", x), text, perl=TRUE)
## [[1]]
## [1]  3  5 12 16 18 21
## attr(,"match.length")
## [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0
## attr(,"useBytes")
## [1] TRUE
```

`sprintf` substitutes the occurrence of `%s` by the value of `x`.

Comment: Yes I almost used `sprintf` instead =)

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`paste0`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/paste.html) which is short for `paste(x, sep="")` ...

```
x <- "GGC"
text <- 'ATGGGCTATGGGCTATGGGCTATGGGCT'
gregexpr(paste0('(?=', x, ')'), text, perl=TRUE)
# [[1]]
# [1]  4 11 18 25
# attr(,"match.length")
# [1] 0 0 0 0
# attr(,"useBytes")
# [1] TRUE
```

And if you want to access the overlapping matches, take a look at [Overlapping matches in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800042/overlapping-matches-in-r)

Answer (score 3):

The `fn$` prefix in gsubfn package supports string interpolation:

```
library(gsubfn)

# test data
text <- "ATGGGCTAAATGGGCT"
x <- "GGGC"

fn$gregexpr("(?=$x)", text, perl = TRUE)
```

See `?fn` , the [gsubfn home page](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) and the gsubfn vignette, `vignette("gsubfn")` .

Answer (score 0):

ok I solved it in this way:

```
text="ATGGGCTAAATGGGCT"
x="GGC"
c=paste("(?=",x,")",sep="")
r=gregexpr(c,text,perl=TRUE)
```