# r ngram extraction with regex

Tags: regex, r, stringi

Karl Broman's post: https://kbroman.wordpress.com/2015/06/22/randomized-hobbit-2/ got me playing with regex and ngrams just for fun.  I attempted to use regex to extract 2-grams.  I know there are parsers to do this but am interested in the regex logic (i.e., it was a self challenge that I failed to meet).

Below I give a minimal example and the desired output.  The problem in my attempt is 2 fold:

1. The grams (words) get eaten up and aren't available for the next pass.  **How can I make them available for the second pass?** (e.g., I want `like` to be available for `like toast` after it's already been consumed previously in `I like`)
2. I couldn't make the space between words non-captured (notice the trailing white space in my output even though I used `(?:\\s*)`).  **How can I not capture trailing spaces on the nth (in this case second) word?** I know this could be done simply with: `"(\\b[A-Za-z']+\\s)(\\b[A-Za-z']+)"` for a 2-gram but I want to extend the solution to n-grams.  PS I know about `\\w` but I don't consider underscores and numbers as word parts, but do consider `'` as a word part.

***MWE:***

```
library(stringi)

x <- "I like toast and jam."

stringi::stri_extract_all_regex(
    x,
    pattern = "((\\b[A-Za-z']+\\b)(?:\\s*)){2}"
)

## [[1]]
## [1] "I like "    "toast and "
```

***Desired Output:***

```
## [[1]]
## [1] "I like"  "like toast"    "toast and"  "and jam"
```

Comment: Maybe the best approach to problem # 2 is: `"(\\b[A-Za-z']+\\s+){1}(\\b[A-Za-z']+)"` where you extend the regex by adjusting the 1 to `n-1`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one way using base R regex. This can be easily extended to handle arbitrary n-grams. The trick is to put the capture group inside a positive look-ahead assertion, eg., `(?=(my_overlapping_pattern))`

```
x <- "I like toast and jam."
pattern <- "(?=(\\b[A-Za-z']+\\b \\b[A-Za-z']+\\b))"
matches<-gregexpr(pattern, x, perl=TRUE)
# a little post-processing needed to get the capture groups with regmatches
attr(matches[[1]], 'match.length') <- as.vector(attr(matches[[1]], 'capture.length')[,1])
regmatches(x, matches)

# [[1]]
# [1] "I like"     "like toast" "toast and"  "and jam"
```

Comment: I think this is related for future searchers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25800334/1000343 The relevant terminology that I was missing is *Overlapping matches*  Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is an app for that: the `quanteda` package (for the quantitative analysis of textual data).  My coauthor Paul Nulty and I are working hard to improve this, but it easily handles the use case you describe.

```
install.packages("quanteda")
require(quanteda)
x <- "I like toast and jam."
> ngrams(x, 2)
## [[1]]
## [1] "i_like"     "like_toast" "toast_and"  "and_jam"   
ngrams(x, n = 2, concatenator = " ", toLower = FALSE)
## [[1]]
## [1] "I like"     "like toast" "toast and"  "and jam"
```

No painful regexes required!

Comment: I yield, you're right about the question but hopefully someone searching for questions about word ngrams will find this useful!

Comment: Thanks, @Ken-Benoit, this looks like a useful package and I am looking forward to checking it out.

Comment: I used this at work today.  Nice upgrades to the package. +1

Comment: Thanks @Tyler Rinker. I hope to have time soon to write some extensions to make it easy to convert or use quanteda objects with qdap. I could start using the "tm-qdap" vignette as a basis.