# Is there a way to use periodicity in a regular expression?

Tags: regex, delimiter, rapidminer

I'm trying to find a regular expression for a `Tokenizer` operator in Rapidminer.

Now, what I'm trying to do is to split text in parts of, let's say, two words.
For example, `That was a good movie.` should result to `That was`, `was a`, `a good`, `good movie`.

What's special about a regex in a tokenizer is that it plays the role of a delimiter, so you match the splitting point and not what you're trying to keep.

Thus the first thought is to use `\s` in order to split on white spaces, but that would result in getting each word separately.

So, my question is how could I force the expression to somehow skip one in two whitespaces?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we can use the \W for identifying the characters that separate the words. And for removing multiple consecutive instances of them, we will use:

```
\W+
```

Having that in mind, you want to split every 2 instances of characters that are included in the "\W+" expression. Thus, the result must be strings that have the following form:

```
<a "word"> <separators that are matched by the pattern "\W+"> <another "word">
```

This means that each token you get from the split you are asking for will have to be further split using the pattern "\W+", in order to obtain the 2 "words" that form it.

For doing the first split you can try this formula:

```
\w+\W+\w+\K\W+
```

Then, for each token you have to tokenize it again using:

```
\W+
```

For getting tokens of 3 "words", you can use the following pattern for the initial split:

```
\w+\W+\w+\W+\w+\K\W+
```

This approach makes use of the \K feature that removes from the match everything that has been captured from the regex up to that point, and starts a new match that will be returned. So essentially, we do: match a word, match separators, match another word, forget everything, match separators and return only those.

In RapidMiner, this can be implemented with 2 consecutive regex tokenizers, the first with the above formula and the second with only the separators to be used within each token (\W+).

Also note that, the pattern \w selects only Latin characters, so if your documents contain text in a different character set, these characters will be consumed by the \W which is supposed to match the separators. If you want to capture text with non-Latin character sets, like Greek for example, you need to change the formula like this:

```
\p{L}+\P{L}+\p{L}+\K\P{L}+
```

Furthermore, if you want the formula to capture text on one language and not on another language, you can modify it accordingly, by specifying {*Language_Identifier*} in place of {L}. For example, if you only want to capture text in Greek, you will use "{Greek}", or "{InGreek}" which is what RapidMiner [supports](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use a zero width group (like a positive look-ahead, as shown in example). Regex usually "consumes" characters it checks, but with a positive lookahead/lookbehind, you assert that characters exist without preventing further checks from checking those letters too.

This should work for your purposes:

```regex
(\w+)(?=(\W+\w+))
```

The following pattern matches for each pair of two words (note that it won't match the last word since it does not have a pair). The first word is in the first capture group, `(\w+)`. Then a positive lookahead includes a match for a sequence of non word characters `\W+` and then another string of word characters `\w+`. The lookahead `(?=...)` the second word is not "consumed".

[Here is a link to a demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/UIN8mM/2)

Note that for each match, each word is in its own capture group (group 1, group 2)

Comment: This doesn't work as I described. I found out that the solution for this problem is related to n-grams, take a look at this https://regex101.com/r/UIN8mM/3

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/UIN8mM/5) is an example solution, `(?=(\b[A-Za-z]+\s[A-Za-z]+))` inspired from this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31003084/r-ngram-extraction-with-regex).
My question sounds wrong once you understand that is a problem of an overlapping regex pattern.