# str_count with overlapping substrings

Tags: r, stringr

I am trying to count the number of appearances of a substring within a character vector. For example:

```
lookin<-c("babababa", "bellow", "ra;baba")
searchfor<-"aba"
str_count(lookin, searchfor)
```

returns: 
2 0 1

However, I want it to return '3 0 1' but it isn't picking up on the middle 'aba' in the first item since it is partially used in the first instance (I think).

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878992/finding-the-indexes-of-multiple-overlapping-matching-substrings/7879329#7879329) but couldn't figure out how to use that with a vector having multiple items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
str_count(lookin, paste0("(?=",searchfor,")"))

[1] 3 0 1
```

Which, as answered in your link, uses lookahead to match all instances.