# R: "perl" regular expression does not recognize patterns when used with 'postive lookbehnd'

Tags: r, regex, pcre

I expect the following code to recognize all the patterns (pat1, pat2, pat3, pat4). However, this recognize only the 'pat4'. How should I modify my code?

```
test.pat<-"pat1|pat2|pat3|((?<=abcd)(.|\n)*pat4)"

originalTXT<-"start abcd pat1 pat2 pat3 pat4"

gregexpr(test.pat, originalTXT, perl=TRUE)

[[1]]

[1] 11

attr(,"match.length")

[1] 20

attr(,"useBytes")

[1] TRUE

attr(,"capture.start")

[1,] 11 26

attr(,"capture.length")

[1,] 20 1

attr(,"capture.names")

[1] "" ""
```

If I omit the "pat4" which used 'positive lookbehind', there's no problem.

```
test.pat<-"pat1|pat2|pat3" 

originalTXT<-"start abcd pat1 pat2 pat3 pat4"

gregexpr(test.pat, originalTXT, perl=TRUE)

[[1]]

[1] 12 17 22

attr(,"match.length")

[1] 4 4 4

attr(,"useBytes")

[1] TRUE
```

Comment: You expecting to be returned overlapping matches (pos 12, length 3; and pos 11, length 20), but the function doesn't do that. It looks for subsequent matches no earlier than the end of the previous one.

Comment: Not sure I know what the error is but I do suspect that `\n` is unlikely to match anything useful. In R regex patterns, backslashes are almost never single.

Comment: @42-, That would be an issue for `\s`, but not for `\n` (since both a literal line feed and `\n` match a line feed).

Comment: Color me surprised. All three of "\n", "\\n", and "\\\n" as patterns match a "\n" (even without perl=TRUE).

Comment: @42-, The last one works because you can safely escape non-word characters in a regex pattern, and a line feed is not a word character. A line feed doesn't require escaping since it has no special meaning to the regex engine, which is why the first one works. Finally, the two char sequence by the middle literal is recognized by the regex engine to mean "match a line feed", so that also works.

Comment: But I thought patterns needed to go first through the R parsing engine (which would use the first backslash as an escape char to make the second backslash a "real" backslash) before the escaped-n got sent to the regex code.

Comment: @ikegami, Thank you so much for you advice. I found [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878992/finding-the-indexes-of-multiple-overlapping-matching-substrings/7879329#7879329) & [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31609721/r-str-count-with-overlapping-substrings), which solved the problem.

Comment: Although this is a duplicate question, I did not delete this question because of the meaningful discussion between ikegami and 42-. If I should delete this question, please tell me. I solved this problem by using the following code: test.pat<-"pat1|pat2|pat3|(?=(?<=abcd)(.|\n)*pat4)".