# extracting multiple overlapping substrings

Tags: regex, r, string

i have strings of amino-acids like this:

```
x <- "MEALYRAQVLVDLT*MQLPSSFAALAAQFDQL*EKEKF*SLIARSLHRPQ**LLMFSLLVASVFTPCSALPFWSIKFTLFILS*SFLISDSILFIRVIDQEIKYVVPL*DLK*LTPDYCKCD*"
```

and i would like to extract all non-overlapping substrings starting with `M` and finishing with `*`. so, for the above example i would need:

```
#[1] "MEALYRAQVLVDLT*"
#[2] "MQLPSSFAALAAQFDQL*"
#[3] "MFSLLVASVFTPCSALPFWSIKFTLFILS*"
```

as the output. predictably `regexpr` gives me the greedy solution:

```
  regmatches(x, regexpr("M.+\\*", x))
 #[1] "MEALYRAQVLVDLT*MQLPSSFAALAAQFDQL*EKEKF*SLIARSLHRPQ**LLMFSLLVASVFTPCSALPFWSIKFTLFILS*SFLISDSILFIRVIDQEIKYVVPL*DLK*LTPDYCKCD*"
```

i have also tried things suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878992/finding-the-indexes-of-multiple-overlapping-matching-substrings), as this is the question that resembles my problem the most (but not quite), but to no avail.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried non-greedy? M.+?\\*

Comment: no, but someone has just suggested it in an answer below and it works!

Comment: I don't understand, you say you know the difference between `greedy` and `non-greedy` ? How can that be ?

Comment: @Frank - I've never seen a regex tutorial that explains `greedy` without explaining  `non-greedy`. One can't exist without the other.

Comment: @Frank - Greed follows quantifiers. Quantifiers are never explained without greed, to know one is to know the other.

Comment: @sln Anywho, I'll delete my comments in a few minutes (to clear up the "noise"). If there's more to say, I'm easily found in the "R public" chat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will add an option for capture of non-overlapping patterns as you requested. We have to check that another pattern hasn't begun within our match:

```
regmatches(x, gregexpr("M[^M]+?\\*", x))[[1]]
#[1] "MEALYRAQVLVDLT*"               
#[2] "MQLPSSFAALAAQFDQL*"            
#[3] "MFSLLVASVFTPCSALPFWSIKFTLFILS*"
```

Comment: yes, that does it, even with intermitten `M`s - thank you

Answer (score 3):

Use a non-greedy `.+?` instead of `.+`, and switch to `gregexpr` for *multiple* matches:

```
R> regmatches(x, gregexpr("M.+?\\*", x))[[1]]
#"MEALYRAQVLVDLT*"                
#"MQLPSSFAALAAQFDQL*"             
#"MFSLLVASVFTPCSALPFWSIKFTLFILS*"
```

Comment: thanks, that's perfect! i have tried `gregexpr` before just forgot to include in my question description. but it was the non-greedy `.+` that did the trick.

Comment: You said "non-overlapping". This fails on `x <- "MABC*MabcMdef*ghi*"`

Answer (score 1):

```
M[^*]+\\*
```

use negated character class.See demo.Also use `perl=True` option.

https://regex101.com/r/tD0dU9/6

Comment: thanks! it works perfectly. i have tried negating `*` but didn't realise that i then didn't need `.` etc.

Comment: Works fine (giving the same result as the other answer) without `perl=TRUE`. Besides, in R, you'd have to write it all caps.

Comment: @Frank we can use `M[^M*]+\\*` where the other answer will fail on `MABC*MabcMdef*ghi*`

Comment: @vks Okay. Seems too late to alter your answer, arguably, as Pierre just posted that. Up to you.