# use a variable within Lookahead

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to use regexpr in R to find overlapping matches; following the elegant solution posted here: [Finding the indexes of multiple/overlapping matching substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878992/finding-the-indexes-of-multiple-overlapping-matching-substrings) , I am trying to use a variable as pattern:

```
myString<- 'abccdccdca'
myPattern<- 'ccdc'
#This Works
gregexpr(pattern = "(?=ccdc)", text = myString, ignore.case = TRUE) 
#This DOES NOT Work:
gregexpr(pattern = "(?=myPattern)", text = myString, ignore.case = TRUE)
```

The latter reads `myPattern` as a string. I have done some search, using perl `$` and `{}` operators, but I don't seem to be able to make it work. I would be grateful for any help :)

Comment: `pattern = paste0("(?=",myPattern,")")`

Comment: Thank you, it works now! If you like, you can post your comment as an answer and I will accept it. Care to help me understand the syntax a bit better, please?